# Find all references to a server in connection strings

Tags: excel, powershell, connection-string

I started a job where they use PC as SQL servers and I want to migrate them to real servers. My problem is I have no idea how many or where all these forms and reports that use this database server are.

I need a way to find all references to a server name in a SQL connection string, mostly in excel, but not limited to. Powershell would be preferred but not necessary. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: You could try `([regex]'(?i)(?:server|source)=([^;]+)').Match($connectionString).Groups[1].Value`

Comment: Sorry, I am little more than a novice in powershell. I have looked up possible ways to use your suggestion and failed. I tried Get-Content and Select-String with no luck. Can you give a bit more to your suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Excel files are basically .ZIP files with a couple of XML files inside. In order to read anything from that, I suggest you have a look at the [Import-Excel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.4.2) module, because `Get-Content` won't do any good there.